# Django forms and MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

Trying to create a form where you can sign up as a user, and add yourself to one or more categories. Getting an error while doing it:

> TypeError at /users/add-user/
>
> > 'categories' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Here's my forms.py:

```
class AddUser(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    title = forms.CharField()
    website = forms.CharField(required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all())
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

The last line is the one I'm having trouble with.

Here's my views.py:

```
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            try:
                p = User.objects.get(email=cd['email'])
                error = "There's already a user with that e-mail adress registered. Maybe he/she is already here?"
                return render_to_response('users/add_user.html', {'form': form, 'error': error}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                p = User(name=cd['name'], title=cd['title'], website=cd['website'], email=cd['email'], phone=cd['phone'], company=cd['company'], categories=cd['categories'])
                p.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../thanks/')
    else:
        form = AddUser(request.POST)
        error = "You can't really submit empty forms. Try adding something useful :)"       
    return render_to_response('users/add_user.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If anyone has any suggestions to the problem (or even suggestions in general to improve my code), I'd be glad! I'm a beginner to Django and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you've extended the django User model somehow, please add it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
p = User(name=cd['name'], title=cd['title'], website=cd['website'], email=cd['email'], phone=cd['phone'], company=cd['company'], categories=cd['categories'])
```

The problem is that the User model doesn't include a categories field, just as it doesn't include a website or company. See the [list of the available fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#fields).

There's different approaches to handling additional data in combination with Django's auth system. Sublcassing the User class or adding a model with additional info and a one-to-one field to the User come to mind. The latter option seems to be [suggested](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), so I'd suggest going down that path.

Comment: Ah. Is this because I've called the model User? Because this isn't supposed to be part of the Django Auth-system. (there will be no login or logout etc.) Will naming it "Member" or "Fellow" fix the problem?

Comment: And btw. website, company, title etc. works. It's only the categories-field I'm having an issue with.

User Models.py:


categories = models.ManyToManyField('categories.Category', related_name='users', blank=True)

Comment: Mats, please include the User model definition then. The name 'User' isn't a problem per so, but you should definitely mention it in your answer.
You'll probably also want to have a look at ModelForm's; they'll save you the step of defining a form for a User instance altogether.

Comment: Thanks Maik :) I changed User to People (all over the place) and went for ModelForms. That made it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a nit pick, but you did ask for other suggestions.  This bit:

```
else:
    form = AddUser(request.POST)
```

should (IMO) be changed to this:

```
else:
    form = AddUser()
```

There's no need to use request.POST for a GET request.  I've never tried that but I'm guessing it will work, you just get an empty set.  So not an error but possibly a source of confusion.

Your error message is also not being used.  A GET on the page is not an error at all in this case, it is just how the page is initially displayed.